# Access primary address of ESP-BLE-MESH publishing node in ESP-IDF

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, esp32, esp-idf, bluetooth-mesh

I have a simple BLE mesh (using Espressif's ESP-BLE-MESH) consisting of two nodes; one containing 3 generic onoff server elements publishing to a group, and one containing a single generic onoff client subscribed to that group. Each node is a little ESP32 dev board with an RGB LED built in. I'm programming in C, using the ESP-IDF extension for Visual Studio Code.

I want the 3 onoff servers to control the R, G and B of the LED, respectively, but all I have to distinguish a server from the others is the address of its element, which is the primary address of the node + some offset. I want to get that offset to determine which of R, G and B are being switched, but I can't figure out how to access the primary address of the publishing node to work that out. I've trawled the documentation and tried every member of the `esp_ble_mesh_generic_client_cb_param_t` struct passed to the `example_ble_mesh_generic_client_cb` function, going down such rabbit holes as `param->params->model->pub->publish_addr`, but have been unsuccessful. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

Server and client code used: [ble mesh node](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/d500c8205ea4a00ca5ed79c0d0230361f71e6d4c/examples/bluetooth/esp_ble_mesh/ble_mesh_node)

Comment: ```param->ctx.addr``` ?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny that gives the address of the specific element (ie primary address + index), which I do need, but isn't what I'm trying to find